# SSMS ADD IN : Status bar color

Tags: sql, add-in, ssms-2012

I'm writing a `SSMS` Add in (`SQL 2012`).
I'm trying to change the status bar color but How ?
The documentation is too poor and I have searched during hours.
I'm blocked Here:

```
TextDocument document = (EnvDTE.TextDocument)ServiceCache.ExtensibilityModel.Application.ActiveDocument.Object(null);
```

And Now . I haven't found any property for changing the status bar color.

The goal is to adapt the Status bar color when changing the connection.
If `Servername` contains "`PROD`", then the status bar has to red.

Thanks a lot

Aurélien